# My regex doesn't match each line individually

Tags: regex

Regex:
`^[^\d]*(?:(\d).*(\d))[^\d]*$`

Working example:

```
aaa 1 bbb 2 ccc 3 ddd
```

Non working example:

```
aaa 1 bbb 2 ccc 3 ddd
eee 4 fff 5 ggg 6 hhh
```

How do I have to change the regex for it to match

```
1 & 3 for the first line
4 & 6 for the last line
```

Comment: Which language is the regex being executed in, and if there are multiple methods to execute a regex, as in JS, which one is being used?

Comment: Why have you grouped `(?:(\d).*(\d))`? This is equivalent: `(\d).*(\d)`. Also, you can replace `[^\d]` with `\D`

Comment: @Bohemian thank you, but I still need some help to get it work with multiple lines. Here you can see it work with one line: https://regex101.com/r/SjyZqK/1

But if you add another line it breaks down and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` and `$` match start and end of *input*.

To make them match start and end of *line*, add the MULTILINE flag, which is regex flavour dependant.

In Java, it's `(?m)`:

```
(?m)^\D*(\d).*(\d)\D*$
```

In JavaScript, it's the `m` flag:

```
/^\D*(\d).*(\d)\D*$/m
```

Note also the simplification of your regex.

Comment: ...or `^.*?(\d).*(\d).*$`, and if there is no need to match the line (e.g., if only the contents of the capture groups are of interest), `^.*?(\d).*(\d)` will suffice. Readers: since `.*` is greedy it will gobble up all digits before the last one. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/10xOYU/1)

Answer (score 0):

When an input string is multiline, it should be interpreted as many lines, as indicated by the `m` flag.  When m is used, for example, `^` and `$` match not just at the beginning or end of the string but also at the beginning or end of any line that is contained in the string.

- in JS or PHP: `/regex/m`
- in Python: `re.compile("regex", re.MULTILINE)`
- in Java: `(?m)regex`

So in your case, you just need to add the multiline flag, check this [Demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/en/regex-tester/17e127b34094).